# how to get the data value returned from a get Ajax request using jquery?

Tags: jquery

how to get a certain data value returned from a get Ajax request using jquery?

Example of the content of level_1_File

```
<p data-test_name="level_1"> Level 1 test results have passed </p>
```

This is the jquery code to get the data attribute of test_name but not working. No alert message is being displayed.

```
                $.get(level_1_File, function(data)
                {
                      if($(data).data("test_name") === "level_1")
                      {
                            alert($(this).text());
                      }

                });
```

Comment: `alert($(this).text());` should be `alert($(data).text());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(data) in condition but $(this) in alert.

Comment: is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: This is answer. In `if` condition you checks data attribute of `$(data)` expression, but in alert you try to output content of `$(this)` statement, that is not the same as data. Should be `alert($(data).text())`

Comment: thanks for clarifying my misunderstanding but the alert is still not working after using alert($(data).text()) but without using the if condition and just using alert(data), I see all the data in the alert

Comment: It is strange. I've created the simplest example demonstrates your code at http://jsfiddle.net/Mj9NN/ and it works. If your function receives the data you've been specified, then alert should work.

Comment: For me it works even with `if` http://jsfiddle.net/UtxRw/ (Tested in latter Chrome)